# Вычисляет ли svg другие элементы вне окна просмотра?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

У меня есть несколько объектов, перемещающихся за пределы окна просмотра SVG в React. Ради оптимизации хотелось бы их условно отрендерить. Таким образом, объекты снаружи не будут отображаться. Но я спрашиваю себя, действительно ли это нужно. Вычисляет ли SVG то, что находится за пределами окна просмотра?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Does a svg compute outside of viewbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70028803/7394871) от участника  [@user13583939](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583939/user13583939).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/70028803/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Браузер вычисляет для рендеринга всё что находится за пределами окна просмотра. Вычисляет, но не показывает в окне просмотра. Поэтому вопрос актуален только в смысле производительности рендеринга. Если часть  очень большого файла svg с большим количеством мелких деталей находится вне окна просмотра, то рендеринг будет затруднен. Хотя при этом будет показана только видимая часть SVG.

*Комментарии автора вопроса:*

> Я просто делаю эффект 2.5d, поэтому у меня есть опора для пикселей,
> распределенных по оси x. Я знаю, где это все, и мне просто нужен
> расчет ширины окна просмотра.

### Расчет ширины окна просмотра (viewBox)

Ниже пример с двумя фигурами SVG. Одна фигура находится внутри svg viewBox, вторая снаружи

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300" style="border:1px solid" >  
  <g>
<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="200" rx="5%" fill="purple" />
           <!--Окружность с координатой цетра - cx = "800" снаружи при viewBox = "0 0 600 300" -->
<circle cx="800" cy="150" r="140" fill="greenyellow" />
</g>
</svg>
```

***Круг находится за пределами svg холста, поэтому он не отображается в браузере.***

Вот так это выглядит в векторном редакторе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы обе фигуры находились внутри svg холста нужно рассчитать параметры viewBox.
Для этого помещаем обе фигуры в групповой тег `<g>` и рассчитываем параметры viewBox

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300" style="border:1px solid" >  
         
  <g id="group">
<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="200" rx="5%" fill="purple" />
           <!--Окружность с координатой цетра - cx = "800" снаружи при viewBox = "0 0 600 300" -->
<circle cx="800" cy="150" r="140" fill="greenyellow" />
</g>
</svg>     

<script>
 console.log(group.getBBox())
</script>
```

***Устанавливаем вычисленные атрибуты viewBox***

Было: viewBox="0 0 600 300"

Стало:  viewBox="20 10 920 280"

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="300" viewBox="20 10 920 280" style="border:1px solid" >  
         
  <g id="group">
<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="200" rx="5%" fill="purple" />
           <!--Окружность с координатой цетра - cx = "800" внутри при viewBox = "0 0 600 300" -->
</g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70032007/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>